# Eloquent query with two models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need your help, please!
I have two models `customer` and `membership`. Customer `hasMany` Memberships.
I need to extract all customers with a membership `active`. I did this but it extracts only memberships, without customers data. How can I change it to solve the problem?

```
Membership::has("customer")
    ->forCompany($companyId)
    ->whereIn('state', ['ATTIVA', 'IN ATTESA DI ESITO', 'DA INVIARE'])
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
            ->orWhereNull('end_date');
    })
```

Comment: You missed a `->get()` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `customers` data with membership you must write the query from `Customers` model and not the `Membership` model. In case you want to eager load the membership with customers data, you must use `with()` method.

So here is the query you want:

```
$customers = Customer::whereHas("memberships",function($q) use ($companyId){

    return $q->forCompany($companyId)
              ->whereIn('state', ['ATTIVA', 'IN ATTESA DI ESITO', 'DA INVIARE'])
              ->where(function ($query) {
                   $query->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                         ->orWhereNull('end_date');
               });

})->with('memberships')->get();
```

So, you can access the memberships of each customer like so:

```
foreach($customers as $customer)
    $memberships = $customer->memberships;
```

Notice : don't forget to define the membersips() method in `Customer` model. Remember to eager load the memberships with customer data using `->with()` method. and don't forget to use `->get()` at the end of query.

[Here](https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-eager-loading) you can read about eager loading.

Comment: The generated query is this:
select * from `customers` where exists (select * from `memberships` where `customers`.`id` = `memberships`.`customer_id` and `company_id` = ? and `state` in (?, ?, ?) and (`end_date` >= ? or `end_date` is null) and `memberships`.`deleted_at` is null) and `customers`.`deleted_at` is null

And it doesn't have "memberships" data....

Comment: @Swim89 the memberships data is under relations property of customer collection. if you use dd() of customers collection you can find it under relations property

Comment: @Swim89 if you get memberships like the way I explained it will appear right away. buy read docs for more info about with() method and eager loading

Answer (score 2):

You want to pull customer and check for it's active membership. Rather your query calls membership first. You query should be:

```
Customer::whereHas('memberships', function ($query) use ($companyId){
    $query
        ->forCompany($companyId)
        ->whereIn('state', ['ATTIVA', 'IN ATTESA DI ESITO', 'DA INVIARE'])
        ->where(function ($sub_query) {
            $sub_query
                ->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                ->orWhereNull('end_date');
        });
    })
    ->with(['memberships'])
    ->get();
```

In above code, 'memberships' is the relationship definition in customer model. Similar as below:

```
public function memberships() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Membership');
}
```